# Multiple linear regression for classification

Tags: regression, classification

Recently I have been playing with linear regression for classification. For the binary case, it is straightforward. For the multiple case, I know there are issues with using this approach (like masking). However, I cannot fully understand how this masking arises. As understand in the multiple case one has to compute a discriminant function for each class and then classify according to the largest value obtained from each function. So why does MLR have issues with masking?

Comment: The terms you're using makes this somewhat unclear. We typically use the *generalized* linear model (eg, logistic regression) to classify, not linear regression. If you're referring to *discriminant function analysis*, that can certainly be used (it's more efficient than logistic reg if the response variables are multivariate normal), but DFA isn't usually called multiple linear regression in my experience. If you want to classify cases into more than 2 categories, you might check out [multinomial logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logit).

Comment: Hello gung. I mean, if you want to apply generalized linear regression to an indicator matrix (0-1), you may get some issue with masking as explained in "The Elements of Statistical Learning" (Hastie et al), chapter 4. That is, many examples will be classified to the wrong class. And I cannot understand the theory behind this issue.

Comment: @gung's point is still a good one that your term "multiple linear regression" is a confusing one in this context.  Could you re-write your question with terminology closer to that used normally?

Comment: Let's say I have k classes, each coded with its index ({1,2,..,k}). I would like to test how linear regression performs on my dataset. I read different approaches to this issue. One uses an indicator matrix, for instance. I wonder whether one need to use a matrix at all. Can't one just apply the regression to a scalar and then classify (somehow). And, of course, the issues coming with this approach that some classes may not be classified (almost) at all.

Comment: I would like to clarify that I want to use least-squares regression to perform the classification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to develop intuition about the genesis of masking is to imagine a one-dimensional problem with three classes each of which has truncated normal PDF (support between -5 and 5) with means of -1, 0, and 1 and the same variance. Now, if one fits a line (using OLS) to a sample drawn from each of these PDFs, it is easy to see that the middle class (the one with the mean of zero) will get a zero slope (flat line) whereas the leftmost class will get negative slope and the rightmost class will get positive slope. This means that, under certain conditions (a particular choice of variance), the middle class might never dominate the other two classes as far as the model value goes which could lead to the middle class being always mis-classified.

Figure 4.3 from the book illustrates that point nicely (that 2-dimensional example can be easily reduced to one-dimensional by projecting the PDFs to the line connecting the centroids of the three classes from Figure 4.2)